# Image processing convolution: Why do I slide my kernel from np.arange(pad, imgWidth+pad)?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, convolution

I am trying to learn kernel convolution for image processing. Now, I understand the concept of kernel convolution, but I am a bit confused about code that I have found for it at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/

Specifically, I am confused about the bounds in the for loops and the location of the convolution output.

```
def convolve(image, kernel):
    # grab the spatial dimensions of the image, along with
    # the spatial dimensions of the kernel
        (iH, iW) = image.shape[:2]
        (kH, kW) = kernel.shape[:2]

    # allocate memory for the output image, taking care to
    # "pad" the borders of the input image so the spatial
    # size (i.e., width and height) are not reduced
    pad = (kW - 1) // 2
    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, pad, pad, pad, pad,
        cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    output = np.zeros((iH, iW), dtype="float32")


    # loop over the input image, "sliding" the kernel across
    # each (x, y)-coordinate from left-to-right and top to
    # bottom
#QUESTION 1 SECTION BEGIN
    for y in np.arange(pad, iH + pad):
        for x in np.arange(pad, iW + pad):
            # extract the ROI of the image by extracting the
            # *center* region of the current (x, y)-coordinates
            # dimensions
            roi = image[y - pad:y + pad + 1, x - pad:x + pad + 1]

#QUESTION 1 SECTION END

    # perform the actual convolution by taking the
    # element-wise multiplication between the ROI and
    # the kernel, then summing the matrix
    k = (roi * kernel).sum()

#QUESTION 2 SECTION BEGIN

    # store the convolved value in the output (x,y)-
    # coordinate of the output image
    output[y - pad, x - pad] = k

#QUESTION 2 SECTION END
```

Question 1: Why is np.arange from pad to iH+pad, and not from pad to iH-pad ? I assume that we start from pad so that the center pixel in the region of interest is never on the edge of the image. However, I would think that going to iH+pad would overshoot and have the center pixel end up outside of image dimensions.

Question 2: This code has us store the output pixel at a location to the left and up from where I centered my convolution roi, no ? If so, could someone explain the logic behind doing this for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`np.arange(pad, iH + pad)` runs over `iH` pixels, which is the width of the original input image. The padded image has a width of `iH + 2*pad`, so this is running from `pad` pixels from the beginning to `pad` pixels from the end of an image column, such that one can index up to `pad` pixels in both directions without exiting the padded image.

Regarding your second question: the input image was padded, the indexing is into the padded image. `image[pad,pad]` obtains the top-left pixel of the original image before padding, and corresponds to `output[0,0]`. `output` is not padded.

Comment: Hi Cris. Thank you for getting back to me. The code actually does work without error.

Comment: And the answer to my second question seems to make sense. My target image is padded, so I need to access "unpadded" pixels in my output. To do this, I "neglect the padding" in my output by subtracting it from the indeces. Correct?

Comment: @ExactPlace441 Indeed, the output image does not have the padding, and so indexing needs to subtract the padding size. I have amended the answer for the first question. I evaluated that too quickly on the first read, and arrived at the wrong conclusion.